# how to find commands related to selenium ide 3.4.5

Tags: command, selenium-ide

when I was making test cases through **selenium ide 3.4.5** and then I wanted to store some values in that but I couldn't find any **command** or link to relate about it. Please help me out with some clue.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the official documentation?

Comment: Yes I tried but command information is not there either